# How to split a single line of code into multiple lines in Go

Tags: go

Is there any way to split a single, really long, line of code into multiple lines. But it would still be treated as a single line of code by compiler.

For example in C++ or in Python, there's `\` which let's us split the same line into multiple lines. 
C++ example code:

```
int min(int a, int b) {
    return a<b ? a : b;
}

int main() {
    int ans = min(4, \
                    5 \
                );
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Here even when I broke the same code min(4,5) into multiple lines it worked.

I tried the same in go but it gave me an error, wondering if there's anyway to achieve the same.
Current go code:

```
return min( \
    query(2*curNode, l, mid, qL, qR, n, st), \
    query(2*curNode+1, mid+1, r, qL, qR, n , st) \
);
```

Getting following error

```
solution.go:37:17: invalid character U+005C '\'
solution.go:38:50: invalid character U+005C '\'
solution.go:39:54: invalid character U+005C '\'
solution.go:39:55: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or )
```

**NOTE**: **query** is just a helper, recursive method, (for querying segment tree) which returns int. And **min** if a function similar to the one in c++ example.

EDIT: Paul and Mondo's suggestions worked,
this will also work:

```
return min(
        query(2*curNode, l, mid, qL, qR, n, st),
        query(2*curNode+1, mid+1, r, qL, qR, n , st),
    );
```

Comment: Just split the line of code over multiple lines without adding the backslashes?

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1:

```
return min(
    query(2*curNode, l, mid, qL, qR, n, st),
    query(2*curNode+1, mid+1, r, qL, qR, n, st),
)
```

Option 2 (preferred):

```
return min(
    query(2*curNode, l, mid, qL, qR, n, st),
    query(2*curNode+1, mid+1, r, qL, qR, n, st))
```

Comment: Underappreciated option 3: use local vars to hold the `query` returns and call `min(queryA,queryB)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split long lines at a comma or at a dot.
remember if it is a comma, sometimes you have to add a comma at the last line, depending on what you are doing.
(For example: adding elements to a slice)